# My Test case never ends

Tags: ios, unit-testing, asynchronous

I am trying to test an async request to the server.
I send the request, get the response, but then the test hangs and does not end

this is my test :

```
-(void)testClearAppsCache{
    XCTestExpectation *expectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"callServicesWithParameters"];
    [self.apiClient callServicesWithParameters:nil//@{@"version":@""}
                                       success:^(BridgeModel *bridge) {
                                           BOOL onMainThread = [NSThread isMainThread];
                                           XCTAssertFalse(onMainThread,@"should be on main thread");
                                           XCTAssertNotNil(bridge);
                                           [expectation fulfill];
                                           NSLog(@"done");
                                       }

                                       failure: ^(NSError * error) {
                                           [expectation fulfill];
                                           LogInfo(@"error gettings services:%@",error);
                                       }];

    [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:5.0 handler:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"waiting for expectation");
        if(error){
            NSLog(@"error:%@",error);
            XCTFail(@"error:%@",error);
        }else {
            XCTAssertNil(error,@"test finished");
        }
    }];

    NSLog(@"done testing");

}
```

This is the log that is printed after the test:

```
2015-09-03 00:16:00.758 MyApp[1960:35258312] I,-[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]:55 application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
2015-09-03 00:16:00.851 MyApp[1960:35258312] Request http://api.something.json?
Test Suite 'Selected tests' started at 2015-09-02 21:16:01 +0000
Test Suite 'MyApp Tests.xctest' started at 2015-09-02 21:16:01 +0000
Test Suite 'ManagerTests' started at 2015-09-02 21:16:01 +0000

2015-09-03 00:16:01.151 MyApp[1960:35258312] I,-[apiClient sendRequest:]:515
sending GET request to path:http:...
2015-09-03 00:16:01.152 MyApp[1960:35258312] D,-[apiClient sendRequest:]:516

2015-09-03 00:16:01.152 MyApp[1960:35258312] D,-[apiClient asyncRequestDataForServerRequest:]:161 added '?'
2015-09-03 00:16:01.152 MyApp[1960:35258312] D,-[apiClient asyncRequestDataForServerRequest:]:165 path with params:http://api.something.json?
2015-09-03 00:16:01.152 MyApp[1960:35258312] D,-[apiClient startRequest:]:183 started connection
2015-09-03 00:16:01.902 MyApp[1960:35258364] D,-[apiClient connection:didReceiveResponse:]:249 Response recieved from url:http://api.something.json?
2015-09-03 00:16:01.902 MyApp[1960:35258348] D,-[apiClient connectionDidFinishLoading:]:267 Data recieved:
2015-09-03 00:16:01.904 MyApp[1960:35258348] D,-[apiClient connectionDidFinishLoading:]:268 statusCode:200
2015-09-03 00:16:03.940 MyApp[1960:35258348] D,-[apiClient connectionDidFinishLoading:]:277 onMainThread?0
2015-09-03 00:16:05.189 MyApp[1960:35258348] done
```

The request runs and succeeds, receives correct response and status code, the success block runs, however after the success block is finished, nothing happens, the test sort of hangs - how can i fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

You are logging after calling `[expectation fulfill];` Your block will probably return before the log statement, appearing to hang, even if it does finish.

Swap the order of the lines, making sure you don't fulfill until the very end.

Comment: that does not help, test still hangs

Comment: I solved the problem, i had a stackoverflow issue and the system just did not report it for some reason ?